# System "tock" sound missing in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, audio

In iOS 6 I used this line:

```
NSString *path  = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.UIKit"] pathForResource:@"Tock" ofType:@"aiff"];
```

to get the path to the system tock sound. Everything was alright. Now since iOS 7, **(null)** is returned as the path.

Can anyone tell me what happened to the tock sound?

I already tried relinking the UIKit.framework library and got the same result. I just can´t find the reason why this line changed it´s result.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can it be due to the fact that Apple moved all old sounds to "Classic" section?

Comment: That´s possible. But can you please go a bit more into detail? How can I access this "classic" section and its sounds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing a quick research in the resources for the SDK, it's not there anymore.

```
[dbarden@Daniels-MacBook-Pro-3/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs]
[16:24:03]% find . -name Tock.aiff
./iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Tock.aiff
./iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Tock.aiff
./iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Tock.aiff
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems like I have to find a new sound. ;-)

Comment: @Daniel Barden where is the iOS 7 Supported system  sound list ?

Answer (score 8):

List of all available system sounds in iOS: [iOSSystemSoundsLibrary](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary).

You can test all sounds with this small demo app

Comment: Thank you sir. Exactly what I needed... this needs more votes!!

Answer (score 3):

This post is top on Google about the topic, so I'll add an alternative answer that took me way too much time to find.

The file is no longer included in the com.apple.UIKit bundle because it's not intended to be used directly anymore. Since iOS 4.2, the intended method to play this sound is

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
```

Hopefully, this prevents anyone else from wasting time trying to find an alternative solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, this can be used only from input views so, if you want to add the sound to a custom button, it requires some hacking (empty input view).

Comment: That is correct. It is only for use in custom input views (Keyboards) and is subject to being enabled/disabled by the user in Settings.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried a similar search on the iPhone Simulator on the 7.0 base sdk:

```
find . -name *.aiff
./System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/lock.aiff
./System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SIMToolkitCallDropped.aiff
./System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SIMToolkitGeneralBeep.aiff
./System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SIMToolkitNegativeACK.aiff
./System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SIMToolkitPositiveACK.aiff
./System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SIMToolkitSMS.aiff
./System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/ussd.aiff
./System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/findme_alarm_2.aiff
./System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/findme_alarm_3.aiff
./System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/findme_alarm_4.aiff
```

Answer (score 1):

That sound is not included anymore, I dont see any other explanation

Answer (score 0):

Here's a copy of the [tock.aiff](https://code.google.com/p/magickeyboard/source/browse/Tock.aiff?r=5ed0b4b73cc1da0d0bb892109df12b5319d6c932) file.

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
 NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                   @"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/%@.%@", @"Tock", @"caf"];
```

it's working for me in `ios7`